# How to display data of json using codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I need some help about PHP json. I am still newbie about this thing. I tried other ways but it seemed unsuccessful. I have this kind of json format:

```
{
        "schedule_backup": [
            {
                "class_time_id_fk": "1",
                "student_id_number": "AR0001",
                "teacher_id_number": "ACAD-0091",
                "class_type_id_fk": "1",
                "room_assignment_id_fk": "4",
                "books_materials_id_fk": "225",
                "class_level_id_fk": "23",
                "subject_id_fk": "57"
            },
            {
                "class_time_id_fk": "2",
                "student_id_number": "AR0001",
                "teacher_id_number": "ACAD-0049",
                "class_type_id_fk": "1",
                "room_assignment_id_fk": "41",
                "books_materials_id_fk": "211",
                "class_level_id_fk": "4",
                "subject_id_fk": "58"
            }
       ]
    }
```

And I want to display them on a table. Here is my code:

**My View**

```
echo $jsonString = $this->MClassSchedule->parse_schedule_backup();

$jsonArray = json_decode($jsonString,true);

echo $jsonArray['schedule_backup']['class_time_id_fk'];
```

**Model**

```
function parse_schedule_backup(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('class_schedule_backup');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    foreach ($query->result() as $rows) {

        return $rows->data;

    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are using Json for this? Will you be using Ajax or is this a straight to view thing?

Comment: Because you are returning and object which doesn't need to be Json decoded unless you want an array. In which case just return a result array and remove your foreach in the model. Then making a table is easy in the view with a foreach.

Comment: @Alex I just to view it. I want to use ajax later on.

Comment: @Alex Could you give an example for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are passing this asynchronously, or through an API, it seems messy to convert it to JSON then back... Just return the data array like in the model below.

**Model**

```
function parse_schedule_backup(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('class_schedule_backup');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    // Return associative data array
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Then in the view, just loop through the rows inside of a table structure. People have different styles for templating tables, but one way is below (obviously not including all columns).

**My View**

```
<?php
// You probably want to do this in the controller and pass the data to the view
$data = $this->MClassSchedule->parse_schedule_backup();
// Create table header
?>
<table>
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>Class ID</th>
           <th>Teacher ID</th>
           <th>Student</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
<?php
    // You probably want to check for a non-empty array and provide an error if needed
    foreach($data as $row){
        $json = json_decode($row['data'], TRUE);
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $json['schedule_backup']['timeID_1']['class_time_id_fk'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $json['schedule_backup']['timeID_1']['student_id_number'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $json['schedule_backup']['timeID_1']['teacher_id_number'] ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php 
    }
?>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I got only the student_id_number the rest is empty.

Comment: Are there data for those other fields in your result? One thing you could do for testing is print the entire row in the `foreach` with say `print_r` to make sure you're getting the values you expect.

Comment: No. Only the student_id_number. In my database table I have ID, student_id_number, data and date_created. Where the json is stored in data row.

Comment: I'm confused now. Where were you getting the JSON object from if not the query provided? Or is the `data` column a JSON string?

Comment: Yes, the data column has a JSON string.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer. Basically, for each row, parse the JSON and you can use it like that. I don't know the specific structure, but assuming it's a single depth object, you can reference it like I did in my answer, otherwise, you'll need to adjust for whichever keys you have.

Comment: I've got an error pointing on `$json` variable.
`Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159590/discussion-between-kchason-and-johnlopev).